# What is the meaning of " I was only to do that"?

Tags: meaning, infinitives, only

I am a non-native English learner.

Does the sentense "I was only to do that" mean "There was nothing I could do"? Gramatically what is "only" here? Is it an adjective or an adverb to modify " be to"?

Comment: Impossible to say without some context.

Answer (score 1):

Without more context, it’s impossible to say for sure, but the most likely meaning is that it means that I was permitted to do just one single thing.

No, *only* is not modifying *to be*. That is not really a verb you can apply an adverb to.  Rather, it here applies to the verb *to do*.

To make it an adjective, you need to apply it to a substantive. For example:

> I was to do only that.
>
> I was to do that only.
>
> Only I was to do that.

Comment: I found this sentence in an English translation by a non-native student. The whole context is the following.   A: Actually, something urgent has come up. B:I have been waiting for you thirty minutes.You should have called much earlier.A:I was only to do that, wasn't I?

Comment: @hirokotosho as a native speaker, that sentence makes no sense in context.

Answer (score 1):

The dialogue posted by the OP isn't very clear; it might have meant at the end:

A: Actually, something urgent has come up.

B: I have been waiting for you thirty minutes.You should have called much earlier.

A: **As though that was the only thing I had to do!** [sarcastic] 
[meaning that he had in fact lots of chores to perform, from which he had been at a difficulty to untangle himself in order to show up on time)

or, alternately:

A: **Remember, I was supposed to only show up on time, not to call you!**